# Fire click event on one element in a set of matched elements and not on matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how to find when my anchor tag is clicked, how to prevent the set of matched elements not to fire.  Here is my Javascript:

```
//open the dialog box
$('.update').click(function (event) {
     var $target = event.target;
     if ($target == $target) {
    $('.update-form').dialog('open');
    console.log('yep');
     } else {
    console.log('nope');
     }

     return false;
});
```

Heres the HTML

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Designer</th>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Detials</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(201, 201, 201); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); ">
        <td>JASZ COUTURE</td>
        <td>4210</td>
        <td>GOLD</td>
        <td>S</td>
        <td> STRAPPY STETCH COCKTAIL</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="http://localhost:8888/lexsreg/index.php/#" class="update">UPDATE</a></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>4as451</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>tes</td>
        <td>tes</td>
        <td><a href="http://localhost:8888/lexsreg/index.php/#" class="update">UPDATE</a></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I know that event.target is returning a value based on the index of the element with the matched set.  How do I tell the other elements to not fire.  Whats happens is, depending on the number of anchor tags with the class of update, will open that many modal windows.  I just need one, not the whole bunch

```
//set the functions of the dialog box
$('.update-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Update': function() {
            //json will happen here
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
    }
});
```

Got a solution its ugly but it works
Give the modal windows equal ids

```
$updateForm.each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

On click pass the event and get the current target id. Traverse the DOM tree and find the modal window whose id matches this.

```
//open the dialog box for the rows
$($btns).click(function(event) {
var target = event.currentTarget.id,
 form = $(this)
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .siblings()
    .children()
    .filter('#'+target);
    $(form).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Could we see the code for `.update-form`? If you're including an element of that class in every `tr`, you'll need to use some jQuery selectors to grab the closest instance to the `a` that's been clicked, but we don't know where this form is. By the looks of things, it's only one instance, but I can't understand what you mean by "how to prevent the set of matched elements not to fire". Could you clarify?

Comment: @JamWaffles yeah I'm a little confused too. @Andre Dublin please let me know if I missed the mark with my answer so I can edit or delete it if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if ($target == $target) {
```

try

```
if ($target == this) {
```

With your approach it would be true for all links which leads to multiple modals opening

Comment: still getting multiple windows.  I know i've seen this problem somewhere before.  I've thought of doing $(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().children().stop(), but thats not elegant.

Comment: Since asking this question I have come across this situation many more times and finally found an elegant approach based on your recomendation @rajaasur.  Use if (this == event.currentTarget) works all the time for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that since you are using a class  $('.update-form').dialog('open'); you are not opening more than one dialog because there are more than one element with that class? i tested your code here and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/aMsbT/1/

EDIT - regarding your comment, to stop proapgation of the event you should use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), to know what part of the DOM triggers your event you should use, as you do event.target

Comment: I know that I'm getting more than one element with the class as a selector.  What I am trying to do is isolate the event on the row clicked and stop the other rows from executing the event.

Comment: To stop event from propagating use stopImmediatePropagation(). but if you click on one anchor only one event is fired (as you can see in the fiddle)